# Making divs as high as possible without ther overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have something like this:

[image: this]

One main "wrapper" div that will have a few divs that are inline.

I can make this, but I don't know how to make the wrapper get as much space as possible, but without getting the scroll bar. And after that I would need to make those 4 inner divs as high as possible

Can I even achieve this with just CSS or would I need a bit of JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex is best for this here is codepen for you

[codepen](https://codepen.io/adamgajzlerowicz/pen/ybXMNE?editors=1100)

```
.top{
  width:100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #00cdcd;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: teal;
}
.child{
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: But that just made container element as high as the screen, it's still overlapping

Comment: You can add `position:absolute;` to the `top` element

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in many ways only with css:

**1st solution:**

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
}
.child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

**2nd solution:**

```
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}
.child {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dinamically size your div with JS:

```
window.onresize = function () {

var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;

document.getElementById('wrapper').style.height = w + 'px';
document.getElementById('wrapper').style.width = h  + 'px';
```

}

so, you can have a precise control for each element in the DOM